# Wordpress - In what moment are the automatic updates done?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using `Wordpress 4.6.X` and then `I would like to know`:

1. How do I check if the `automatic updates` are enabled or not?
2. In what moment are the `automatic updates` done?

I have one website which is maintained by another developer. Via `Git`, I detected this `Wordpress` website has updated some `plugins` and maybe it's `core` (automatically or manually). Then I would like to get the answers to the above questions to get also the answer to `my goal question`, which is as follows:

**My goal question:** How do I know if this website was updated `manually` or `automatically`?

Any other idea to answer **my goal question** would be welcome.

**Note:** I have a local copy of the same website on my own `local server` machine (other than the `live server` above) and no `automatic updates` have been done, what makes me think that maybe the update were done `manually`. That's what I would like to know also in what moment are the `automatic updates` done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want to have total control of your updates, and you want to be sure that your WP website only updates when you or your developers wants, you need to add the following filters and constant to stop the automatic updates:

In your **wp-config.php** add this *(for the core updates)*:

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

In the **functions.php** add this (disable automatic WordPress plugin updates):

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );
```

and this (disable automatic WordPress theme updates):

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );
```

After that, you will be able to know when the updates happens since it's all controlled by you (and/or your developers).

Another (not always reliable) way to check when an update happened is by checking the versions. You can then verify when a *(WP, plugin or theme)* version was released.

Comment: thank you @elcerebrum. The first part is clear. Then about the second part (about the moment), more than the specific time I would like to know what circumstances should happen for the automatic updates get ran. I mean, maybe like: the website runs automatic updates once a day after 00:00 hrs, or every time some page is requested? or what?

Comment: Thanks @elcerebrum